# How to fix link preload warning in Next.js app?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, next.js

I am developing a Next.js app with version 13.4 and I am getting this warning in the console:

```
The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window’s load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

The number of the error is increasing.

The console screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

From the warning image, it looks like you are preloading css files. While using preload, you will need to specify `href` and `as` attributes. I think you have not added `as` attribute.
Add them like this.

```
 <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />
```

Check this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) for more details on this

Comment: How can i add this in next 13 app?

Comment: You don't need to add this whole thing. Just add `as="style"` in those link tags that you are getting warnings for.

Comment: on the inspect's html head section there are lots of css links and the number is increasing everytime i change page, click on an element etc. i don't know why this happened because yesterday everyting was fine. So there are lots of links i am getting warnings.

Comment: but add it to where?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and mine was about google fonts and i managed to solve it by adding preload:true when im trying to access to the font that i want.

Example:

```
export const font = Nunito({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-general",
  preload: true,
});
```

Comment: preload is true by default: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font#preload

Answer (score 1):

If you use Next.js 13 or higher, you may need to add prefetch={false} prop to a Link tag. This step solved a problem, as example: Link href="/contact" prefetch={false}

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with fonts:

> preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make
> sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly

I just removed unused font declarations.

Before:

```
import { Inter, Roboto, Sora } from 'next/font/google

export const inter = Inter({
subsets: ['latin'],
display: 'swap',
variable: '--font-inter'
})

export const roboto = Roboto({
subsets: ['latin'],
display: 'swap',
variable: '--font-roboto',
weight: '500'
})

export const sora = Sora({
subsets: ['latin'],
display: 'swap',
variable: '--font-sora'
})
```

After (I use only Inter font in my NextJS project):

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google

export const inter = Inter({
subsets: ['latin'],
display: 'swap',
variable: '--font-inter'
})
```

It was acording to the official doccumentation (using multiple fonts in NextJS Vercel Project):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#using-multiple-fonts

Comment: It does not leave us to see what font is not being used.